# Эффективность NativeActivity/C++

Tags: android, c++, jni

Есть такая штука, как JNI, и в рамках написания кода для android на с/с++ - этот JNI нужен для вызова Java-функций, которые не могут заменить с/с++ код. Вообще, я так понимаю, JNI - это ооочень обобщённо что-то типа API к Android.

JNI, как я понял, можно вызывать вручную из кода с/с++ или использовать NativeActivity, где эти вызовы скрыты за более удобной "оберткой".

И вот предположим теперь из кода с/с++ нужно обратится, к примеру, к экрану или какому-нибудь датчику, то будет вызван этот вызов JNI и якобы поговаривают, что это ресурсозатратно, особенно, если вызывать это часто.

Если все вышеописанное более менее соответствует истине, то:

А если приложение пишется на чистом Java и нужно опросить тот же датчик, то в таком же случае - это будет менее затратно, чем, если бы был вызван JNI из с/с++?

Comment: в слове jni первая j - это java. jni позволяет с джава кода вызывать Ваш с/с++ код. А вот наоборот... да, можно, но это будет немного странно выглядеть

Comment: JNI расшифровывается как Java Native Interface. Вызовы через границу языка всегда очень затратны. Так что по-возможности их количество стоит минимизировать. NativeActivity мало что предоставляет.